# PHP anonymous function assigned to class property in constructor is always null?

Tags: php

I want to pass anonymous function to class constructor and assign it to its property but it is always null regardless of what i do, is that possible to do?

Sorry guys, it seems that class also extends Thread from php pthread extension:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php , which seems to be the issue somehow.

```
<?php
$execute_action = function ($site, $response) {
    $siteTest = $site;
    echo $siteTest;
    echo $response;
};

class TestClass extends Thread
{
    public $execute_action;

    function __construct($execute_action)
    {
        $this->execute_action = $execute_action;
        var_dump($this->execute_action); // <- Null

        $this->execute_action = Closure::bind($execute_action, $this);
        var_dump($this->execute_action); // <- Null

        $this->execute_action = $execute_action->bindTo($this);
        var_dump($this->execute_action); // <- Null
    }
}

$test = new TestClass($execute_action);
```

Comment: Yes, seems Thread extension is real issue.

Are you sure extension is installed? Enable php errors output.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any reason why it wouldn't work. I ran your code example, but it threw syntax errors so I corrected them and here is what I came up with:

```
<?php
class TestClass
{
    public $execute_action;
    public function __construct($execute_action)
    {
        $this->execute_action = $execute_action;
        var_dump($this->execute_action);
        $this->execute_action = Closure::bind($execute_action, $this);
        var_dump($this->execute_action);
        $this->execute_action = $execute_action->bindTo($this);
        var_dump($this->execute_action);die();
    }
} // Missing close brace

$execute_action = function ($site, $response) {
    $siteTest = $site;
    echo $siteTest;
    echo $response;
}; // Missing semi-colon

$test = new TestClass($execute_action);
```

And this was the output after it ran:

```
object(Closure)#1 (1) {
  ["parameter"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["$site"]=>
    string(10) "<required>"
    ["$response"]=>
    string(10) "<required>"
  }
}
object(Closure)#3 (2) {
  ["this"]=>
  object(TestClass)#2 (1) {
    ["execute_action"]=>
    *RECURSION*
  }
  ["parameter"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["$site"]=>
    string(10) "<required>"
    ["$response"]=>
    string(10) "<required>"
  }
}
object(Closure)#4 (2) {
  ["this"]=>
  object(TestClass)#2 (1) {
    ["execute_action"]=>
    *RECURSION*
  }
  ["parameter"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["$site"]=>
    string(10) "<required>"
    ["$response"]=>
    string(10) "<required>"
  }
}
```

Comment: What php version do you guys use? I use 5.5.27. Can that be the issue?

Comment: I was using PHP 5.6.18, but it looks like Closure's were introduced in 5.3 so you should be fine.

Comment: It seems that it happens when class TestClass extends Thread with above php pthreads extension, i wonder why is that?

Comment: I would try and help debug, but I can't easily install pthreads on my linux box.

Comment: Thx jostrander anyways, i can tell that by debugging that var_dump($execute_action); returns correct object when right in the next line $this->execute_action = $execute_action; - var_dump($this->execute_action); returns null.

Comment: I installed first 2.0.7 version of pthreads, but then I tried to go higher with version 2.9 which actually partially solved that issue. Now, $this->execute_action is not NULL however it seems to contain full object of this TestClass class with execute_action property pointing to the full same objects and it loops like that recursively by some reason... Still trying to figure out how to solve it?

Comment: Example:   object(Closure)#28 (2) { ["this"]=> object(PThread)#45 (10) { ["execute_action "]=> object(Closure)#36 (2) { ["this"]=> object(PThread)#45 (10) { ["execute_action "]=> object(Closure)#35 (2) { ["this"]=> object(PThread)#45 (10) { ["execute_action "]=> object(Closure)#39 (2) { ["this"]=> object(PThread)#45 (10) { ...