# Assigning a function to a property of a class

Tags: php, function, class

I'm trying to do something similar to [PHP anonymous function assigned to class property in constructor is always null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353337/php-anonymous-function-assigned-to-class-property-in-constructor-is-always-null/), but my solution seems more simple. I wanted comments from the Stack Overflow Hot Shots on this solution and whether there is a better one. This is kind of a 'best practices' question.

I want to pass a function (anonymous or defined) to a class/object and be able to call that function later. I started with this :

```
function Foo($arg) {return sprintf('In Foo(%s)',$arg);}
function Bar($arg) {return sprintf('In Bar(%s)',$arg);}

class TestIt {
  private $func;

  public function __construct( $func ) { $this->func = $func; }

  public function OutPut($arg) {
    return $this->func($arg);
  }
}

$test  = new TestIt('Foo');
echo $test->OutPut('Bozo');
```

When this is run, I get an error that the method `$this->func` doesn't exist. If I put a `is_callable` test inside the method `OutPut()`, I find the `$this->func` is, in fact, callable, but the error persists.

However, if I us the third argument of `is_callable`, I get this to work fine.

```
public function OutPut($arg) {
  return is_callable($this->func,false,$tmpfunc) ? $tmpfunc($arg) : null;
}
```

How does this stack up as a solution? Curious of your thoughts.

Comment: Is `__construnt` just a typo in your question or is it also in your code?

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no way to get PHP to parse `$this->func()` as a variable function, you have two options here:

```
return call_user_func_array($this->func, array($arg));
```

Or:

```
$func = $this->func;
return $func($arg);
```

`is_callable()` will return a static method call `someClass::someMethod` even if it is not a static method and is called in object scope.

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the solution with call_user_func_array or my solution with is_callable for the error checking. Would there be any performance differences between these two solutions?

Comment: You could benchmark, but I would expect `is_callable` to have slightly more overhead, and the callable name is always a static name (see edit).